# Jaeger and kubernetes with a public collector ingress

Tags: c#, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, jaeger

### Scenario

I am using helm to facilitate creation of deployments and services for jaeger. Specifically
https://github.com/jaegertracing/helm-charts

I have an application running on the same k8s that pushed traces to
`http://jaeger-collector.observability.svc.cluster.local:4317` and these work fine. (observability is the namespace where jaeger is installed)

Now i also have an external application which I want to forward traces to jaeger aswell.

Helm chart values below

```
...ommitted...
collector:
  enabled: true
  basePath: /
  service:
    otlp:
      grpc:
        name: otlp-grpc
        port: 4317
      http:
        name: otlp-http
        port: 4318
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    ingressClassName: nginx
    hosts:
      host: collector.example.com
...ommitted...
```

### Ingress Problem and workaround

However there is a problem in the above helm chart, it seems to only let me create an ingress for port 14268 only. I have worked around that, and for testing purposes I have updated the generated yml file directly on k8s, and replaced the port as below

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: collector.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: jaeger-collector
                port:
                  number: 4317 #was 14268
```

My expectations were that nginx (ingress controller) will be listetning on port 80 and 443 and will forward all requests to `jaeger-collector`.

### Analysis

This still doesnt work. My collector service is working correctly 100% as applications running on k8's manage to push data. So the **problem** seems to be something with the **ingress** or **something before that**.

From what i can tell, the (modified) ingress is correct.
My application code is .Net C#.

### Application code

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAppTelemetry(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
{
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .ConfigureResource(r => r.AddService(serviceName: webHostEnvironment.ApplicationName))
        .WithTracing(builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddNpgsql()
            .AddRedisInstrumentation()
            .AddOtlpExporter();
        });

    services.Configure<OtlpExporterOptions>(configuration.GetSection("OpenTelemetry:otlp"));

    return services;

}
```

and my appsettings options

```
"OpenTelemetry": {
  "otlp": {
    "Endpoint": "http://collector.example.com:80"
  }
},
```

### Possible issues and solution attempts

1. I am running collector.example.com behind cloudflare proxy, I disabled this to no avail.
2. Curl and telnet to collector.example.com works fine.
3. Tried creating my own ingress instead of the helm one, no luck
4. My own service that listens on port 80/443 and redirects to 4317

At this point I'm out of ideas, I only just learned Helm and jaeger since yesterday, and im quite fresh with k8s aswell. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: drive-by comment: the Jaeger port 4317 is a gRPC endpoint. `Ingress` often don't permit gRPC traffic by default (gRPC requires HTTP/2). See [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/grpc/) for supporting gRPC with NGINX Ingress. I don't know (!) but it may be the issue. One way to confirm this would be to try a tool like [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) against that endpoint. Alternatively (!) 4318 appears to be an HTTP endpoint, you could try exposing that port too|instead) see ports [here](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.52/getting-started/)

Comment: So with 4318 i managed, but only http, and endpoint needed to be `https://collect.example.com/v1/traces`
Now to do https, using cloudflare's SSL, i get  tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority. Will see what this is about now.
Also maybe helpfull to someone else, use the HotROD docker image for debuging jaeger.

Comment: To whoever finds this, the error i was receiveing was just from HotROD, my own application worked fine.